# Autonomous harvesting robots. What are model possible components and interactions for the entire system?

Tags: mobile-robot, robotic-arm, computer-vision, industrial-robot, autonomous-car

I found a video which talk about best autonomous robots that use IA technology to harvest crops. The video is very interesting because, the “ecosystem” of each robot varies a lot from company to company. I am trying to identify with a list of the components which interact (wireless communication) with the robot in such a case, here what I found so far:

- The robot that uses IA techniques for harvesting
- A supporting robot or an autonomous truck which provides empty storage to carry the harvested crops,
- A laptop used to monitor the whole operation for quality purpose

Are there any other components that I might have missed? The only that I can think of is the communication between the robot arm and the carrier which provides the autonomous mobility of the entire robot (this is part of the robot). What are other components that participate in this harvesting operation?

PS: Robotics is an aera outside of my expertise, so please feel free to correct me if I said anything wrong.

Comment: why are you compiling the list?

Comment: think of components that provide support function ... how much of the support function would be automated?

Comment: @jsotola you're suggesting that this depends on design and there isn't a typical sytem model?

Comment: no, I am not suggesring anything like that ... you asked `What are other components that participate in this harvesting operation?` ... I am giving a hint

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Hokage, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to understand, what you've researched so far, what you found & what you expected to find. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and go through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: I don't understand what you're hoping to learn, or what qualifies as being an item on your list. Why are you making the list? If we knew more about your motivation or what problem you're trying to solve then I think you would get more diverse answers. At the moment it reads very open-ended.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing which part is missing in the list is pretty easy. What was provided so far is the robot system itself which contains of the mechanical device, a computer controlled robot and a PC on which the AI software is running. The assumption is that the overall system provides a closed system, which means that the intelligence in the system is able to solve the harvesting task and no further help for the robot is needed. This is equal to an autonomous robot which is self-sufficient because of what?

Right, the reason why the robot doesn't need further advice is because the AI software has reached a certain amount of intelligence which ensures that the system is able to avoid obstacles, can grasp the fruits and can switch off itself if the task is done ...

But let us speculate which part is missing so that the system is working fully autonomous. Or let me answer the question the other way around. Which part is redundant? Perhaps it is possible to combine the laptop with the robot into a single apparatus so that the overall system is reduced to it's minimum and can solve the task more efficient. This would minimize the amount of interface and the amount of communication as well.